# Angular ng-change event not working on first change?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sharepoint-2010, scope

Still learning the ropes with Angular and I have a form that loads students into a select dropdown from a JSON return and I want to change school name label to the school listed as the students school based on the student id. This all part of the JSON and it's working...sort of.  When I select the student from the dropdown nothing happens but if I change selection back to the default the change works and label now has the intended value.

in my .ascx

```
<select name="studentList" ng-model="student" ng-change="getStudent(student)" ng-options="s.StudentID as s.FirstName for s in cStudents | orderBy:'FirstName'">
                <option value="">Choose Students...</option>
            </select>
```

from the controller

```
angularVolunteerApp.controller('vAppController',
function vAppController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.cStudents = $window.xStudents;

    $scope.getStudent = function(xStudent) {

        angular.forEach(xStudents, function (s) {

            if (s.StudentId == xStudent) {
                $scope.cSchoolName = s.SchoolName;
            }
        });

        //$scope.cSchoolName = xStudent;
    };

});
```

Not sure if this is relevant but this is for a webpart in Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Seems like it should work, you don't have all the HTML up there though so we can't see things like the label that should be declaring the school name/etc. If you set up a Plnkr or something I'll look at it and get it figured out for you.

Comment: could you recreate this using my jsfiddle project? I don't have a list of students generated for the dropdown https://jsfiddle.net/jgshultz/mbp2qap2/

Comment: Does not it be more like `if (s.StudentId === xStudent.id)` ?

Comment: @KreepN I've got a Plnkr going but the recreated array for the student doesn't appear to be working and I don't kno why. Angular is working is as it should be.... http://plnkr.co/edit/Ei7L54chG7TRn9JOuH9z?p=preview

Comment: @Rav3nL0g no, you pass the ng-model back on change and that is student id value, which when i set that value to the label is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your main problem, null can't be in caps:

```
"CurrentStatus":null
```

NOT

```
"CurrentStatus":NULL
```

Add that in with the inconsistent naming of variables (casing was not consistent) and you're in for a wild ride!

I fixed it all up for you and made it do what I think you want it to do, check it out here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/o5Y12VUrNX0OHNxJ3dT5?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! The ' $scope.Student = xStudent;' seemed to be what I was missing. The caps on the JSON was just a  bad copy/paste on my part, I was returning the JSON to a label so I could what was being returned and our CSS set the text to caps =P